# VSCode -- how to set working directory for debug C++

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, lldb

I started a simple C++ project using VS Code with C++ extension. My code need to read in a file at "MY_WORKSPACE/../h0"  and do some calculations. I created a "task.json", set   `"options": {  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"`
, Run Build Tasks and the program works.
Then I created "launch.json", set `"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",`  press F5, then "Unable to find input file".

I tried in the Debug Console: `-exec shell pwd`, it shows "MY_WORKSPACE/build"  So it seems the "cwd" option in "launch.json" is not working?

And I'll appreciate any working way to set my cwd at ${workspaceFolder}...

Version:

- My macOS 11.5.2
- VS Code 1.60.1
- lldb-1200.0.44.2
- Apple Swift version 5.3.2 (swiftlang-1200.0.45 clang-1200.0.32.28)
- Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
  Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
  Thread model: posix

Below are my original "task.json":

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "clang++ build src files for DEBUG",
        "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
        "args": [
            "-std=c++17",
            "-stdlib=libc++",
            "-g",
            "src/*.cpp",
            "-o",
            "build/analyzer.out"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/clang++"
    }
]
```

}

"launch.json":

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "clang++ - Build and debug src file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/analyzer.out",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",   /*BUG?: not working */         
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "clang++ build src files for DEBUG"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you run program by using the "run and debug" widget on the side bar? I think your task.json and launch.json will only be used there. Extensions and the "run and debug"(from vs code) are two different systems. Try use "run and debug" on the side bar, then pick your setting file at the top and hit run button.

I only tried once using vscode to debug c++, the setting-up time was not worth the result. You may try using cmake in vscode to set up your c++ debug environment.

Comment: thx! I tried to launch from sidebar, choose my specific configuration, but still the same problem. I think the “launch.json” is being used, as I can see from the debug console that my args are passed correctly

Comment: Now the cwd works after updating vscode….. but the lldb does not respond whenever I step into…..  yes I should discard VScode for cpp debugging…